# How to remove/unload a VB6 Excel COM Add-in from memory, without uninstalling it?

Tags: excel, com, vb6, add-in

I am wondering if anyone knows how can I go about removing a *VB6 COM Add-In* from within the **Excel** environment (i.e., unloading it), through code, but without uninstalling it?

I have tried setting the respective COMAddin "Connect" property to false, with a code like bellow:

```
MyExcellApp.COMAddins("myComAddin").Connect = False
```

While that does unload the add-in from memory, **Excel** will not re-load it again when it is restarted. That is, the *COM Add-in* was in fact uninstalled, and has to be installed back (through Excel's **COM Add-ins** menu option) in order to work again.

Why do I want to do that? Well, I am creating a rather complex *COM Add-in*, and I want to give the end-users an opportunity to unload it if they feel it is disturbing their environment. It will be like an "exit" button for the add-in, but it should allow the add-in to load again whenever **Excel** is re-started.

Comment: It is not uninstalled, merely not loaded.  If you now want to have it loaded again then of course you have to tell it so.  This is exactly what your customer will do.

Comment: Well, one can fake the removal by simply deleting the means by which the end-user interacts with the Add-In, namely a custom toolbar. One "exit" button may simple delete the toolbar (and any other object related to it) indicating to the end-user that the Add-In is not available. Upon re-starting Excel it will load itself again, and re-create a new toolbar. That does it, but I wonder if there is anything more definitive than that.